# Creating Frame inside a Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a frame scrollable, and the only way I found to do this is making a scrollable canvas and adding a frame to it. This would work fine, if it worked for me.

I am able to create a scrollable canvas that works fine, but I can't seem to properly add a frame inside of it:

```
    self.title = Label(root, text="Brnr", font=("Helvetica", 50), anchor = W, pady = 40, padx = 50)
    self.title.pack (anchor = NW)
    #creates title widget for title

    self.frame = Frame(screen, bd =1)
    self.frame.pack(fill = BOTH)
    #Creates frame widget under which all other widgets will be kept

    self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame,  bd=1,scrollregion=(0,0, 1000, 1000), height = 600)
    #creates canvas so that screen can be scrollable

    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.frame, command=self.canvas.yview)
    #creates scrollbar

    self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)  
    #connects the scrollbar to the canvas

    self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)                     
    self.canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH) 
    #packs the scrollbar and canvas so that they fill the remainder of the screen


    self.frameC = Frame(bg = "red")
    self.canvas.create_window(0,0, anchor = NW, window = self.frameC, width = 200, height = 200)
    #creates window on the scrollable area to add other widgets

    self.frameC.pack()
    self.groupRec = LabelFrame(self.frameC, text ="Recommendations:", font=("Helvetica", 20))
    self.groupRec.pack()
    self.signupButton = Button(self.groupRec, text="Sign Up", width=10)
    self.signupButton.pack(side=RIGHT)
    #creates button to submit login
```

This gives me a scrollable, but empty, canvas, with none of the labelframe/button appearing.

Answer (score 7):

By default, when  you add a window to a canvas, the center of the window will be at the coordinates you give. Thus, the center of your frame will be at 0,0 which is the upper-left corner of the canvas. You can't see the widgets because they are outside the borders of the canvas.

The solution is to include `anchor="nw"` in the call to `create_window`, which will place the upper-left corner of your frame in the upper left corner of your canvas.

Don't forget to set the scroll region of the canvas to match the size of your frame. The easiest way to do that is with the command `self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))`.  You'll probably also need to add a binding to `<Configure>` on the canvas so that you can resize the inner frame when the user resizes the window. That's not always necessary, it depends a bit on exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Here's a pro tip: to debug problems like this it's really helpful to temporarily give your frame and canvas different colors to more easily visualize what is happening.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! Now I followed what you told me to do (anchoring) and it did not change anything. Once I added colour to the frame, nothing changed either. This leads me to believe its not being properly inserting into the canvas? Any recommendation? THanks!

Comment: When I used the exact code in your question, along with the few lines you omitted plus the changes I suggested, it worked fine. Are you certain the code in your question is _exactly_ what you are using?

Comment: That's very strange, so I'll show you all parts of my code in the update

Comment: @Victor Mota: no, you have introduced many bugs into your code unrelated to the problem you ask about in the question. You inherit from tk.Tk yet you don't import Tkinter as tk; you make the title a child of "root" but in that context root doesn't exist (the parent should be "self"), self.frame is a child of "screen" but you don't define "screen" anywhere, and that's when I quit trying to make your code work.

Answer (score 4):

Don't re-invent the wheel.  Install Pmw (Python meta-widgets), assuming you are using Tkinter, http://pmw.sourceforge.net/ and use Pmw.ScrolledFrame.